# What do they all mean?

Tags: riddle

> Middle names of two pres'dents,
>   and one of a time traveler,
>   A most famous sorceress,
>   and a programmer's laughter.
>   A call for assistance,
>   an invisible juncture.
>   *What do they all mean?*
>   (One word is the answer.)

---

Hint

> Not looking for a pattern like one proposed by @cwallenpoole. All of the words described mean "something". What is that "something" ?

Hint 2
Edited first line of riddle

Comment: Just to be sure, is there a mistake on the first line "pres'dents" ? Or is it done on purpose ?

Comment: It's "presidents", nothing special there, just changed it for the rhythm.

Answer (score 4):

They're all three's.

The names of two pres'dents,

> JFK, FDR

and one of a time traveler,

> "Doc"

A most famous sorceress,

> "Red" woman from GoT or "Fay" as in "Morgen le Fay"

and a programmer's laughter.

> LOL

A call for assistance,

> SOS

an invisible juncture.

??? This one is hard. Don't know, but I would guess:

> Net (as in network/internet)

Comment: Wrong answer, but some guesses are "coincidentally" right : call for assistance is the correct word, time traveler and invisible juncture are close